# Android insert listview with searchview results

Tags: android, android-actionbar, searchview

I want to display a `ListView` with item results from a `SearchView` request like this:

[image]

I don't want to use ActionbarSherlock and I can not find any tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Custom Suggestions](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-custom-suggestions.html#TheBasics) in the menu xml for the ActionBar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/app_label"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint"
    android:searchSuggestAuthority="com.example.MyCustomSuggestionProvider">
</searchable>
```

or create the autocompletetextview in the layout and add the Layout Inflator and set the setCustom

```
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
   LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) this
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.yourlayout, null);

      actionBar.setCustomView(v);
```

Comment: Autocompletetextview was the solution

Comment: I think it's more simple actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.yourlayout);